# How should I store the current position of tabs during a postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am storing the current position of tab using ctl0 . is this the right method for storing the current tab value. I read some where use client id bcz it will mismatch during run time. how i am get client id. i am storing using hidden field.What am i doing wrong
**this my HTML**

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab1'>
    <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2'>
    <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab3'>
    <p>And this is the 3rd tab.</p>
  </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
            // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
            // which tab is active and it's associated content
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');


            // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
            // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
            if ($('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() == "") {
                $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val(location.hash)
            }

            $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content = $($active.attr('href'));

            window.location.href = window.location.href.toString() + $active.attr('href');


            // Hide the remaining content
            $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
            });


            // Bind the click event handler
            $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {

                // Make the old tab inactive.
                $active.removeClass('active');
                //window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().replace($active.attr('href'), '');
                $content.hide();

                // Update the variables with the new link and content
                $active = $(this);
                $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val($active.attr("href"))
                $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + $active.attr('href');

                // Make the tab active.
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();



                // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

**vb code**

```
 hdnCurrentTabSelection.Value = Request.Form(hdnCurrentTabSelection.UniqueID)
```

***aspx code**

```
 <input type="hidden" ID="hdnCurrentTabSelection"  runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the hiddencontrol inside any container or not. To be safe, you can do like this in jquery:
Instead of this:

```
$('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val()
```

Use this:

```
$('#<%= hdnCurrentTabSelection.ClientID %>').val()
```

Also, this line of code doesnot match with what you are doing, I would suggest **commenting it out**:

```
hdnCurrentTabSelection.Value = Request.Form(hdnCurrentTabSelection.UniqueID)
```

**You are missing `;` in many places in your jquery.** You need to fix them to work.